# Need to Preserve Border Width on Hover without Moving Elements Around

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ive been trying to come up with a solution to a problem I have with no luck for quite some time.  I have a grid of equal-sized squares that go 7 across and 4 down and resize depending on screen resolution.  My code for each row looks something like this (though I have tried pure image formatting without any background properties also)

```
<!--1st Row-->
<div style="background-color:black; overflow:auto; height:auto;">
<img src="images/restalksquare.jpg" style="width:14.27%; display:inline;" id="after" class="sizing">
<img src="images/C2,-R1.jpg" style="width:14.27%; display:inline;" class="dark boxes sizing">
<img src="images/C3,-R1.jpg" style="width:14.27%; display:inline;" class="dark boxes sizing">
<img src="images/C4,-R1.jpg" style="width:14.27%; display:inline; position:static; z-index:101;" class="boxes dark hover sizing">
<img src="images/empty.jpg" style="width:14.27%; display:inline;" class="sizing">
<img src="images/C6,-R1.jpg" style="width:14.27%; display:inline;" class="hover sizing topright">
<img src="images/C7,-R1.jpg" style="width:14.27%; display:inline;" class="hover sizing topright">
```

The Grids are all supposed to have a border of about 4-5 px solid white; and squares in a certain class become darker when scrolled over.  I've tried different solutions to this but one of the main ones I'd been using was a method where I set the contain to div to 'background-color:black' and then used a JQuery method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".dark").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".dark").fadeTo(0, 0.5);})
 ;});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".dark").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".dark").fadeTo(0.5, 1);
});});
```

This method was working to darken the squares; but the client also needed the borders within those sections (not the borders that did NOT get darker) to stay the same; and have the same amount of space exist between images.  However, moth methods I've used either move the entire screen around, or fill up the half of the space within the div with a darker shade when the opacity is lowered; but I want the full border space on both sides to remain at full opacity.

```
.hover2{
outline: 0px !important;
}
.hover{
outline:3px solid white;
outline-offset:-3px;
}
```

The .hover class is set to certain div before hover; while the .hover2 class "appears" on hover, causing the (entire) outline to disappear, when I need to preserve that outline on one side to maintain the white space ratio between boxes.

There's also a slight flicker when you move your mouse very quickly over the text which I'd love to figure out too; made it so .dark stays at low opacity and with no borders when entering the text area as well and applied a fade effect method to allow it to appear at full opacity despite being the same class.

I have also tried 'border' and 'box-shadow' properties to no avail.

This is the site: http://residentalk.com/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider revising your question into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without resorting to sending users to an external site.

Comment: have you tried `outline: 3px solid transparent` for hover 2?